# Efficient use of Python list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a Python list of objects that could be pretty long. At particular times, I'm interested in all of the elements in the list that have a certain attribute, say `flag`, that evaluates to False. To do so, I've been using a list comprehension, like this:

```
objList = list()
# ... populate list
[x for x in objList if not x.flag]
```

Which seems to work well. After forming the sublist, I have a few different operations that I might need to do:

1. Subscript the sublist to get the element at index `ind`.
2. Calculate the length of the sublist (i.e. the number of elements that have `flag == False`).
3. Search the sublist for the first instance of a particular object (i.e. using the list's `.index()` method).

I've implemented these using the naive approach of just forming the sublist and then using its methods to get at the data I want. I'm wondering if there are more efficient ways to go about these. #1 and #3 at least seem like they could be optimized, because in #1 I only need the first `ind + 1` matching elements of the sublist, not necessarily the entire result set, and in #3 I only need to search through the sublist until I find a matching element.

Is there a good Pythonic way to do this? I'm guessing I might be able to use the `()` syntax in some way to get a generator instead of creating the entire list, but I haven't happened upon the right way yet. I obviously could write loops manually, but I'm looking for something as elegant as the comprehension-based method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do any of these operations a couple of times, the overhead of other methods will be higher, the list is the best way. It's also probably the clearest, so if memory isn't a problem, then I'd recommend just going with it.

If memory/speed is a problem, then there are alternatives - note that speed-wise, these might actually be slower, depending on the common case for your software.

For your scenarios:

```
#value = sublist[n]
value = nth(x for x in objList if not x.flag, n)

#value = len(sublist)
value = sum(not x.flag for x in objList)

#value = sublist.index(target)
value = next(dropwhile(lambda x: x != target, (x for x in objList if not x.flag)))
```

Using [`itertools.dropwhile()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) and [the `nth()` recipe](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the itertools docs.

Comment: Why `consume()` instead of `nth()`?

Comment: @KennyTM Great suggestion, should have read on a bit - edited to use ``nth()``, which is a much nicer solution - no point reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you might do any of these three things, and you might do them more than once.

In that case, what you want is basically to write a lazily evaluated list class. It would keep two pieces of data, a *real* `list` cache of evaluated items, and a generator of the rest. You could then do `ll[10]` and it would evaluate up to the 10th item, `ll.index('spam')` and it would evaluate until it finds `'spam'`, and then `len(ll)` and it would evaluate the rest of the list, all the while caching in the real list what it sees so nothing is done more than once.

Constructing it would look like this:

```
LazyList(x for x in obj_list if not x.flag)
```

But nothing would actually be computed until you actually start using it as above.

Comment: With that approach, I would need some way of notifying the `LazyList` instance if the underlying list changes. I wasn't explicit about that in the OP, but `objList` can change between the times that I would search it.

Comment: In that case you would just have to create a new `LazyList`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you commented that your `objList` can change, if you don't *also* need to index or search objList itself, then you might be better off just storing two different lists, one with `.flag = True` and one with `.flag = False`. Then you can use the second list directly instead of constructing it with a list comprehension each time.

If this works in your situation, it is likely the most efficient way to do it.